# How big of a cut on skin renders an animal treif

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, shiurim-measurements, chulin-tractate

According to Halacha, how big of a cut on an animal’s skin is necessary to render it non kosher (treif)? Not depth, but width/length wise, what is the shiur for it to become prohibited? Is this discussed in the Talmud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are eight signs that can render an animal *treif* (see e.g., [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/the-laws-of-treifos-understanding-chalak-glat-kosher-meat-tzomes-hagidin-buka-deutma-sirchos/)) and put an animal on the verge of death. Some of them have to do with external cuts, and they each come with specific characteristics, e.g.,

- ***derusa*** which applies to certain animals (e.g., a lion, wolf, eagle, cat) attacking certain animals (e.g., large domesticated animals, lamb, fowl) but not in all combinations. When attacked we need to check the entire animal for signs of *tereifa*. **The signs of *tereifa* start when the flesh turns red, in which case even the slightest wound is significant** (see MT [Hilchot Schechitah chapter 5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971831/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-5.htm) at length for details)
- ***nekuva*** which is a **perforation of the slightest size** that reaches the inner cavity of 11 key organs: the entrance to the gullet, the membrane of the brain in the skull, the heart and its large arteries, the gall-bladder, the arteries leading to the liver, the maw, the stomach, the abdomen, the gut, the intestines, and the lung and the bronchia (see MT [Hilchot Schechitah chapter 6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971832/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-6.htm) at length for details)

These laws are also covered by [SA YD 55](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.55.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and following, and find their sources in the gemara Chulin.